# why google don't use DOCTYPE in its HTML?

Tags: html, doctype

I know DOCTYPE is important because some CSS rules need specific DOCTYPE.
but why some sites like google.com don't specify DOCTYPE for their HTML?

Comment: A quick test shows that Google says `<doctype html>` at the beginning of its search page, so which Google page are you talking about?

Comment: Google do use a Doctype (at least in the sample of pages on the google.com domain that I just checked).

Comment: google.com uses the html5 doctype.  Can you provide examples of where one is missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The doctype is not necessary, it can be omitted:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/

See chapter 2.2. The DOCTYPE:

> "The HTML syntax of HTML5 requires a DOCTYPE to be specified to ensure that the browser renders the page in standards mode. The DOCTYPE has no other purpose and is therefore optional for XML. Documents with an XML media type are always handled in standards mode. [DOCTYPE]
>
> The DOCTYPE declaration is < !DOCTYPE html> and is case-insensitive in the HTML syntax. DOCTYPEs from earlier versions of HTML were longer because the HTML language was SGML-based and therefore required a reference to a DTD. With HTML5 this is no longer the case and the DOCTYPE is only needed to enable standards mode for documents written using the HTML syntax. Browsers already do this for < !DOCTYPE html>."

Though I think it should be used to avoid confusions.

Comment: "The doctype is not necessary" as a generic statement is false, you want to put in a doctype unless you really want your page rendered in quirks mode.

Comment: The question was: why does google omit the doctype - and my answer was: because it's optional.

Answer (score 1):

Using simply `<doctype html>` is enough for browsers to switch standart compliant mode. So there's no need to waste bytes for long doctypes.